# How can I turn off or hide animated emoji icons in subject lines in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, emoji

Recently I've been receiving spam and commercial emails that include special unicode characters in the subject line that display as tiny animated icons in the Gmail web app.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095387/animated-icon-in-email-subject) on Stack Overflow explains what they are and how they work.

I find the animations extremely distracting when they are displayed in a list of emails by subject. Is there any way to turn them off or hide them?

Comment: There is now an open-source Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/Violentmonkey userscript to solve this problem: the [Gmail Subject Line Emoji Roach Motel](https://lurkertech.com/emoji/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cross-posted to [Turn off or hide email icons that display in Gmail subject lines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87546/turn-off-or-hide-email-icons-that-display-in-gmail-subject-lines)*

## Short Answer

The [Gmail web app](http://mail.google.com) doesn't include an option to turn off or hide the animated icons shown in the subject. One way to do this is by using the CSS property `{display:none}` to elements having the `goomoji` attribute.

### Code

*Simplest code*
This will hide all the emojis in the Gmail web UI.

```
[goomoji]{
    display:none;
}
```

*Hide only emojis in the subject* (not tested yet)

```
.y6>span>img[goomoji]{
    display:none;
}
```

## Explanation

Animated icons are called [emojis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji), they were [incorporated as UNICODE characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#In_the_Unicode_Standard) from 2010. As they aren't supported by all computer operating systems and web browsers Gmail replace them by using the attribute `goomoji`.

Cascading Style Sheets (`CSS`) is a language used for the presentation of web pages. One of its elements are `selectors` which are used to specify the presentation settings of HTML elements.

To help users to apply custom `CSS`, aka `user styles`, there are extensions for web browsers. One of them is [Stylish for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe).

## References

- [Animated icon in email subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28095387/1595451)
- https://userstyles.org/

Comment: Animated icons are not called "emojis". Emoji are static. The animated goomoji are not part of the unicode character standard.